# Replace values in one pandas dataframe using boolean values from another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, substitution

I have two pandas dataframes, one containing data and another consisting of True/False values

1. `iris`

| Sepal.Length | Sepal.Width | Petal.Length | Petal.Width | Species |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5.1 | 3.5 | 1.4 | 0.2 | setosa |
| 4.9 | 3.0 | 1.4 | 0.2 | setosa |
| 4.7 | 3.2 | 1.3 | 0.2 | setosa |

2. `iris_bool`

| Sepal.Length | Sepal.Width | Petal.Length | Petal.Width | Species |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | False | True | False | False |
| False | True | False | False | False |
| False | False | False | False | True |

I would like to replace values in table 1 with NA/NaNs based on the corresponding boolean in table 2. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `mask`:

```
iris = iris.mask(~iris_bool)
```

Output:

```
>>> iris
   Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width Species
0           5.1          NaN           1.4          NaN     NaN
1           NaN          3.0           NaN          NaN     NaN
2           NaN          NaN           NaN          NaN  setosa
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! Do you mind if I ask what the ~ is doing in this expression?

Comment: It's inverting it, so every True becomes False and every False becomes True.

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign

```
iris[~iris_bool]=np.nan
```